# How to determining if a file has been selected in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to validate an uploading form, one of the conditions is to check if any file has been selected. I thought this would be simple, but I can't get it to work. Is this code invalid? The var file works with other conditions so it's not that

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');

if(file.value =="") {
    alert("no file selected")
    return false;
}

<input  name="uploaded" type="file" id="file" />
```

Comment: I vaguely remember not being able to get the value of a file input for security reasons. I may be wrong.

Comment: Are you calling document.getElementById('file') before the file input tag exists?

Comment: Ok, I have put that condition first, and now it works, problem solved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following example:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
fileInput.onchange = function () {
    var input = this.files[0]; 
    if (input) {
        //process input.
    } else {
        alert("Please select a file.");
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for that.  I did manage to make it work by making it the first condition, but always good to know alternative methods